# Вопрос по фокусам в EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

есть 3 поля EditText .нужно настроить их так что бы фокус после заполнения поле перескакивал на следующее поле. И (!) после стирания данных из поля (допустим №2)курсор автоматически перескакивал на пред идущее(№1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.tok.my2.MainActivity">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text|number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:id="@+id/editTextCardNumber"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:hint="номер карты"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/editTextValidity"
    android:digits="0123456789 "
    android:maxLength="19"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editTextCVV"
    android:id="@+id/editTextValidity"
    android:hint="срок действия"
    android:inputType="text|number"

    android:nextFocusForward="@+id/editTextCVV"
    android:digits="0123456789/"
    android:maxLength="5"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text|number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTextCardNumber"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:id="@+id/editTextCVV"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/editTextCardNumber"
    android:hint="CVV"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:digits="0123456789"
    android:maxLength="3"/>

<Button
    android:text="OK"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTextValidity"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:elevation="0dp" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Все гораздо проще, можно просто обойтись флагами в разметке `nextFocusDown/Left/Forward` и т.д.:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/editText2" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/editText2" 
/>
```

Comment: что то не получилось

Answer (score 0):

Смена фокуса делается следующим образом:

```
editText1.clearFocus();
editText2.requestFocus();
editText2.setCursorVisible(true);
```

А вот логику после которого будет отрабатывать данное действие, нужно писать самому